# Incorrect address displayed by bpf_printk

Tags: exception, kernel, ebpf, page-fault, tracepoint

I have a eBPF function that is attached to the `page_fault_user` tracepoint.

```
struct trace_event_raw_x86_exceptions {
    struct trace_entry ent;
    long unsigned int address;
    long unsigned int ip;
    long unsigned int error_code;
    char __data[0];
};

SEC("tp/exceptions/page_fault_user")
int handle_tp(trace_event_raw_x86_exceptions *ctx)
{
    bpf_printk("page-fault-user at %p.\n", ctx->address);
    return 0;
}
```

`struct trace_event_raw_x86_exceptions` is defined according to the contents of `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/exceptions/page_fault_user/format`. However, I cannot get correct faulting address form `ctx->address`.

I have confirmed that the eBPF function `handle_tp` is successfully attached to the `page_fault_user` tracepoint, but `bpf_printk` prints incorrect faulting address.

Answer (score 1):

> [printk-formats](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt): Pointers printed without a specifier extension (i.e unadorned %p) are
> hashed to give a unique identifier without leaking kernel addresses to user
> space.

Use `%ps` in `bff_printk` solved my problem.